# Reducibility of polynomials in two variables in different level sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a polynomial $g\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, is there a way to determine for which $c\in \mathbb{C}$ we have that $g-c$ is reducible?

For example, if we define $h=x^2y+xy+x$, we have that $h=x(xy+y+1)$ and $h+1=(xy+1)(x+1)$.

So in this example, $h+c$ is reducible for $c=0$ or $1$.

Comment: Do you know Bezout's theorem? If $g-c$ factors, then the zero loci of the two factors intersect, at least in the projective plane $P^2(\Bbb{C})$, and a point of intersection will be a singularity. Those you can detect using the gradient because the additive constant does not affect the gradient at all! For example with $h=x^2y+xy+x$ we get $\nabla h=(2xy+y+1,x^2+x)$. The latter component vanishes at $x=0$ or $x=-1$. Plugging those into the first component tells us that the critical points are $(0,-1)$ and $(-1,1)$. These points satisfy $h(x,y)+c=0$ when $c=0$ and $c=1$ respectively.

Comment: To detect possible singularities on the line at infinity you need to homogenize, but the procedure is about the same.

Comment: IMPORTANT: this is just a necessary condition for reducibility, not a sufficient one. A plane curve can be irreducible and still have singularities. Anyway, I think this may be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply @JyrkiLahtonen. Can you explain me how you do the procedure on the line at infinity? At least for a example without finite singular points such as $h=x(xy + 1)^2 + x^2y^2$?

Comment: Hmm. May be I was speeding? Looks like $c$ survives differentiation after homogenization :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Well I found out a brute force approach, probably not very satisfatory. If we take for example $h=x(xy+1)^2+x^2y^2$, since it has degree 5, if it factors in a level $c$, it must have a factor of degree  $\leq 2$, and its Newton polygon must be contained in the Newton polygon of $h$.  So we evaluate the resultant of $h-c$ and $mxy+nx+o$ in $x$ to find that it can be zero only when $c=1$, $c=0$ or $m,n,o=0$. So the candidates are $0$ and $-1$ and in fact $h=x \left( {x}^{2}{y}^{2}+x{y}^{2}+2\,xy+1 \right) $ and $h-1= \left( xy+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}y+xy+x-1 \right) $.